# MongoDB C# - update using custom strongly-typed objects not allowed?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-query

I am trying to perform an update using strongly-typed objects. For example,

```
public void setAppointmentPrefs(string UserName, IEnumerable<AppointmentInfo> info)
{
    var query = new QueryDocument {{ "ProviderId", UserName}};
    var update = Update.Set("Prefs",prefs);    // prefs.toList() gives same error
    // providerprefs initialized in constructor
    providerprefs.Update(query, update);
}
```

I receive a compiler error saying:`Error    14  The best overloaded method match for 'MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set(string, MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue)' has some invalid arguments`

Obviously the Mongo driver will not let me update based on my own object (whether as IEnumerable or prefs.toList()), which seems a contrast from the way it permits me to insert or query with custom objects. Surely I am missing something obvious that would permit me to avoid deserializing, weakly typing then creating a generic BsonDocument!! TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You can do an Update based on your own types! Have you tried using the typed Query and Update builders?

Try something like this:

```
var query = Query<AppointmentInfo>.EQ(i => i.ProviderId, userName);
var update = Update<AppointmentInfo>.Set(i => i.Prefs, info.Prefs);
```

Not sure I got the types and everything write from your partial code, but that should give you the general idea.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered but I for one don't fully understand Roberts answer.

All I did is call the "ToBsonDocument()" method for it to except the object as a parameter

So:

```
customObject.ToBsonDocument()
```

If you have an array of objects inside a document:

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(id.ToString()));
var update = Update.Push("ArrayOfObjects", customObject.ToBsonDocument());
collection.Update(query, update);
```